# angular-google-maps - "_contains is not a function" in chrome

Tags: lodash, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to use angular-google-maps but it breaks in chrome with the error

```
TypeError: _.contains is not a function
```

My DOM element looks like

```
<div id="dashboard_map" class="tab-pane fade in active" ng-controller="mapsCtrl" ng-init="url = '/api/companies'; initialise();">
  <div class="panel panel-default"  ng-hide="!custom">
    <div class="panel-heading row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {!! Lang::get('google_maps.map1.title') !!}
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
      <i class="filter glyphicon glyphicon-filter pull-right" ng-click="custom=!custom"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="map_canvas">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I am loading gmap3, gmap3menu, lodash, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-simple-logger and finally angular-google-maps in that order. My controller contains the following $scope property

```
$scope.map = {center: {latitude: 40.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 4 };
```

The map is displayed but I cannot get rid of the error.

Any ideas/advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the error, the only advice i can give is to look for a line with a `_.contains`.

Answer (score 7):

Installing angular-google-maps via bower resolves(in my case) lodash to version 4. Aparently from version 3.* to 4 changes 'contains' for 'includes' and 'object' for 'zipObject'.
As indicated [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1682) i solved with:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
      if( typeof _.contains === 'undefined' ) {
        _.contains = _.includes;
      }
      if( typeof _.object === 'undefined' ) {
        _.object = _.zipObject;
      }
      $scope.map = {..map stuff}
})
```

Sorry for the bad english, please edit to correct

Answer (score 4):

Which version of `lodash` do you have? I can see `contains` as an alias for `includes` in the [3.10.1 version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.js), but not in the [master](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js).  (Just search for the word *contains*)

Answer (score 1):

Newest versions of angular-google-maps require lodash 4 as dependency (but lodash replaced _.contains with _.includes [they were aliases before version 4]). so might need to choose lower version of lodash for your project (maybe a popup came up asking you which version of lodash you wanted when installing stuff via 'bower install'), or ask angular-google-maps to fix (me and someone else just did that coincidentally just now
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1682
)

Comment: Note: supposedly this is fixed. May want to try out latest master

Answer (score 0):

try to add this script to your index.html after including the lodash lib

```
    <script>
    _.contains = _.includes;
   </script>
```